# Refreshing Tabbar Tab When Button is Pressing

Tags: android, ios, flutter, tabbar

I have a tabbar and I'm using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to keep tabs current states, but I cannot refresh tabs whenever I want because I use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMix`, How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is bad idea to create filenames with utf-8 characters. It is better to use simple names.